# Create Flex 3d components

Tags: apache-flex, 3d, components

What can be the right way for creating flex 3d components based on existing FLex components.
For example if I want to make a 3D DataGrid using existing spark Data Grid. 
Is it possible to do this like creating a 3D skin in Flash , through Maya and after that trying to apply this flash component to skin class of the data Grid.

Also is it possible to use Spark DataGrid with Proscenium. IN fact to see my DataDrid in 3D space.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible since all Flex components extend from DisplayObject, which cannot be used in stage3D. You'd have to recreate the entire component stack in a 3D version.

Comment: Components extends UiComponent which extend FlexSprite which extends Sprite

Comment: What you mean with component stack?

Comment: or the other way is it be possible to add DataGrid to Proscenium and there a can using from point 3d object to add to DataGrid and for other point to keep busines logic of component

Comment: And Sprite eventually extends DisplayObject. With component stack I mean that if you would want to create a 3D DataGrid for example, you would have to rewrite UIComponent so that it (indirectly) extends the 3D version of DisplayObject, then rewrite SkinnableComponent, then SkinnableContainerBase, and then DataGrid.

Comment: But in general I have to rewrite only the visual part (drawing) the business logic of component in most will be the same.

Comment: Also what do you think for the other option to use DataGrid in with 3D stage Proscenium

Comment: 1./ Not if you want to leverage stage3D; you'll have to rewrite everything. 2./ Sorry, I don't know Proscenium; I could imagine a scenario where you'd project a regular DataGrid on a 3D plane, but certainly nothing more.

Comment: Proscenium it's Adobe  product similar to Alternativa and Flasre3d . Hmm so maybe first i will try to put DataGrid on the 3D plane and to see can I mix this with some kind of 3D skin in this environment or the other way to try to  rewrite component stack, which will be a lot of work , but it will be fun . Thank you for your answers.